# how to fix scaling problem when using ifft in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to get the time signal of `X(W)` which as shown in the code below is `X(W)=1./(-omega.^2*m+1i*c.*omega+k);` I am using `ifft` on MATLAB, but the `time_domain_signal` that I get is lower in magnitude than the `x_impl` which is the analytical solution. I think I am missing something with the step size of time and frequency so I get a difference in scaling.

Would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
%system parameters
m=1;
k=1;
omega_n=sqrt(k/m);
c=0.2;
xi=c/(2*sqrt(k*m));
omega_d=omega_n*sqrt(1-xi^2);

%frequency range
omega=0:0.1:10;
f=omega/(2*pi);

% X(W), impulse response of a single dof in the frequency domain
X=1./(-omega.^2*m+1i*c.*omega+k); 

reconstructed_fft = [X flip(conj(X))];
time_domain_signal = ifft(reconstructed_fft,'symmetric'); % getting the response in time domain

Fn = 2* max(f) ;
N = length(time_domain_signal);
t=0:1/(Fn): (N-1)/(Fn) ;

%analytical solution
x_impl=1*exp(-xi*omega_n.*t).*sin(omega_d*t)/(m*omega_d); %impose response function

figure
plot(t,time_domain_signal)
hold on
plot(t,x_impl)
```

[image: the difference in scaling shown in the figure as well]

Comment: That factor of pi should be a big hint for you (try `time_domain_signal = 3.14.*ifft(reconstructed_fft,'symmetric');`)

Answer (score 0):

It's a scaling problem:

```
% Fn, which should actually be 3.14, but is not because 
% omega=0:0.1:10;  
% f=omega/(2*pi);
% Fn = 2* max(f);
reconstructedfft_scaled = Fn*reconstructedfft; 
time_domain_signal = ifft(reconstructedfft_scaled, N, "symmetric");
```

You need to scale the reconstructed fft before the ifft, or even after, since they are linear (multiplying all of fft is equivilant to multiplying all of ifft).

Results:

[image: After scaling]